# Laravel Website: Upgraded hosting to Dedicated, Now the form & admin won't work

Tags: php, laravel

On shared hosting (Namecheap) everything worked fine. Upgraded to (Namecheap) dedicated server and now Admin and Form won't work. Namecheap says 'We can't find any issues on our end".

Anyone been through this?

I've tried everything mentioned on stackoverflow.

Error message is

> 419 page expired.

Comment: It's a typical csrf error. Check your code. Do you get any error? Show us some code.

Comment: Yes, that's a mismatching token error. Is your server load balanced? Has session storage changed or anything like that?